# How to escape double quotes in a column name when querying Excel file using ODBC

Tags: sql, excel, escaping, odbc, double-quotes

I need to query an Excel file using ODBC.
A sheet, `Sheet1` has a column that contains double quotes. For example, he"llo.

Querying the sheet without that column yields correct results, for instance:

`SELECT "test" FROM "Sheet1$"`

But when a column contains double quotes, I'm unable to query it. I've read somewhere you can escape those quotes by adding double quotes, but the following query `SELECT "he""llo" FROM "Sheet1$"` yields the following error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[he][llo]'.

I have tried all sorts of ways to escape that character but to no avail.
Please note that changing the data source is not an option, or at least a last resort option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The escape is by *adding* a *pair* of double-quotes (i.e., changing from `SELECT "he"llo"` to `SELECT "he"""llo"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
When a column contains double quotes, you can change the quoted identifier to back ticks. You can even mix them with regular quoting for other columns such as:

`` SELECT "test", `he"llo` FROM "Sheet1$" ``

Hope this helps someone else as well!